# Foreach on collection cast to IEnumerable work slower than without cast?

Tags: c#, linq

Today I found something that I don't quite understand. I got the [following code](http://share.linqpad.net/hjrvrl.linq) in LinqPad (version 5):

```
void Main()
{
    const int size = 5000000;
    List<Thing> things = Enumerable.Range(1, 5000000).Select(x => new Thing {Id = x}).ToList();

    var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    foreach (var t in things)
        if(t.Id == size) break;
    sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();

    var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    IEnumerable<Thing> ienThings = things;
    foreach (var t in ienThings)
        if (t.Id == size) break;
    sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();

}

class Thing
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

It appears that second loop takes twice as long as the first one. Why would this simple cast cause such an effect? I'm sure that there's something simple happening under the hood that I am somehow missing.

Comment: If you really want to compare 2 loops - at least move `var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();` one line below to omit calculation of time required for your new collection

Comment: @SerhiyChupryk That's not a new collection it's just a different type of reference to the same collection.  The time to run that line should be inconsequential.

Comment: You should check the IL this is compiling to. I get similar times with 5,000,000, 50,000,000, and 500,000,000 items in the collections, which strongly suggests the loop is being optimised out.

Comment: @IainGalloway regardless of optimization turned on or not IL says that different GetEnumerator method is being called. I would expect that thanks to polymorphism it would always be the List.GetEnumerator, but it appears not to be true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the difference between the `call` and `callvirt` instruction used.

```
call        System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+Thing>+Enumerator.get_Current
call        System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+Thing>+Enumerator.MoveNext
```

vs

```
callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<UserQuery+Thing>.get_Current
callvirt    System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext
```

The `callvirt` instruction does a null check, that is why it is slower.